# How to call the same directive in different views through one controller

Tags: angularjs

I have one directive which looks like this

```
.directive('audioPlay', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

      var player = element.children('.player')[0];
      scope.playOrPause = true;

      scope.playMusic = function() {
        scope.playOrPause = false;
        player.play();
      }

      scope.stopMusic = function() {
        scope.playOrPause = true;
        player.pause();
      }

    }
  };
})
```

I am using this directive to play and pause audio

```
<audio-play>
  <audio class="player">
    <source src="http://fire.wavestreamer.com:9711/UrbanetRadio"/>
  </audio>
  <button ng-click="playMusic()"
          ng-hide="!playOrPause">
  </button>
  <button ng-click="stopMusic()"
          ng-show="!playOrPause">
  </button>
</audio-play>
```

this is an app where I need to have that audio in every view, it doesn't matter where the user goes, the live streaming should be there.

I have a controller attached to the tabs which is an abstract view, so that controller is everywhere the user goes, I need to call that directive and attache it to that controller, how can I do that ?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Do you just need one high-level controller that doesn't go away when the page state changes?

Comment: I have a controller attached to the body already. The problem is that this directive is only in one view so far, so if you go to another view the sound goes off. So I need to have that directive attached to the controller that I have attached to the body element @tandrewnichols

Comment: So you want to know how to access that `scope` object from inside the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the answers to your problem (that don't involve restructuring your html hierarchy) are somewhat dirty.

1) Use $rootScope instead of scope. You can inject things in directives, so redefine your directive as:

```
.directive('audioPlay', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {

      var player = element.children('.player')[0];
      $rootScope.playOrPause = true;

      $rootScope.playMusic = function() {
        $rootScope.playOrPause = false;
        player.play();
      }

      $rootScope.stopMusic = function() {
        $rootScope.playOrPause = true;
        player.pause();
      }

    }
  };
})
```

That's dirty because you don't want to be throwing things on $rootScope unless you have to. It's like `window`. It's global to the angular app and gets cluttered quickly.

2) Manually grab the scope you're interested in.

```
.directive('audioPlay', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      var $scope = $('[ng-controller="WhateverController"]').scope();
      var player = element.children('.player')[0];
      $scope.playOrPause = true;

      $scope.playMusic = function() {
        $scope.playOrPause = false;
        player.play();
      }

      $scope.stopMusic = function() {
        $scope.playOrPause = true;
        player.pause();
      }

    }
  };
})
```

This is dirty . . . just, so dirty it shouldn't have been spoken out loud.

Is there a reason you can't just put `playMusic` and `stopMusic` on the *actual scope* inside the controller? It seems like a bad idea to me to be defining new functions on a scope from inside a directive.

Comment: I don't have where to put the player, I mean, if I put it in one single view, once I move to another view, the sounds goes off. So, what can I do to have the sound in every single view ?

Comment: You need to put it in a top level view that doesn't change with an inner view that does. Like `<div ng-controller="ThisControllerNeverDies"><!--controls here --><div ng-view></div></div>`. I guess I was still misunderstanding what you were asking. I can add this to the answer if it's helpful.

Comment: tomorrow I will be doing the question again with the full code and deeper explanation and I'll be tagging you. I am leaving now. thank you man

Answer (score 1):

If you want the player to be in all views, that indicates that it should be present in the root view, and the nested views will not contain it. You should re structure your views hierarchy.

Comment: I have de index.html and then I have tabs.html which is the abstract view, but I need to have a button in the nav bar where the user can play and pause the music. So it is not a thing of html structure.